# seeding a seed.js & seed.sql files in rails4(using both SQL & Mongoid databases)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have a seed.js file and a seed.sql file with seed data in my /db/ folder that I need to seed to my rails project.

I have 2 models running on SQL and two others on Mongoid. How can I seed both of these file formats to their respective models? It seems that rails rake db:seed command only loads from the seed.rb file. I haven't any useful information on this.

Thanks!